# Hide axis and gridlines Highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

I am trying to hide the axis and gridlines of my Highcharts chart entirely.
So far I have tried to set the width of the lines to 0, but it didn't work out.

```
xAxis: {
  lineWidth: 0,
  minorGridLineWidth: 0,
  lineColor: 'transparent'
}
```

Is it possible to just globally disable the axis lines/ticks and gridlines to create a "plain" plot?

Comment: Here's [how to hide the yAxis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277405/highchart-show-hide-an-y-axis-without-hiding-the-series)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Just add

```
xAxis: {
   ...  
   lineWidth: 0,
   minorGridLineWidth: 0,
   lineColor: 'transparent',
   ...          
   labels: {
       enabled: false
   },
   minorTickLength: 0,
   tickLength: 0
}
```

to the xAxis definition.

Since Version 4.1.9 you can simply use the axis attribute `visible`:

```
xAxis: {
    visible: false,
}
```

Comment: @dgw This makes the x-axis transparent, but it still occupies physical space under the data. Is there a way to give it 0 height as well?

Comment: That's a bit overkill. HighCharts should implement a simple property called "visible" that would toggle whether an axis is displayed or not. I've posted that as a [feature request and you can vote for it here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/5164818-control-axis-visibility-show-hide-toggle-axes).

Comment: `minorGridLineWidth` was the obscure property I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @TrevorBurnham - To remove the physical space that had tickmarks, you need to set chart.spacing = [0, 0, 0, 0] (or just set whatever axis, like chart.spacingLeft, to zero, if you don't want to eliminate all spacing). That was the missing piece for me for this question.

Comment: I can still see the axes in 3D! When options3d: { enabled: true }.

Comment: `tickLength: 0` seemed to be all I needed to hide the tick marks on my line chart.

Answer (score 83):

For the `yAxis` you'll also need:

`gridLineColor: 'transparent',`

Comment: Do you also need to set the `title.text` to `null`? Anyway, HighCharts should just implement a simple property called "visible" that would toggle whether an axis is displayed or not. I've posted that as a [feature request and you can vote for it here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/5164818-control-axis-visibility-show-hide-toggle-axes).

Comment: setting `gridLineColor` to `transparent` may prematurely remove the grid lines if you still have other axes to remove. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/39xBU/54/).

Answer (score 30):

If you have bigger version than v4.9 of Highcharts you can use `visible: false` in the `xAxis` and `yAxis` settings.

Example:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts axis visibility'
    },

    xAxis: {
        visible: false
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit'
        },
        visible: false
    }

});
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 22):

you can also hide the gridline on yAxis as:

```
yAxis:{ 
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  minorGridLineWidth: 0
}
```

Answer (score 5):

i managed to turn off mine with just

```
       lineColor: 'transparent',
       tickLength: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

If you doesn't want to touch the config object, you just hide the grid by css:

```
.chart-container .highcharts-grid {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This has always worked well for me:

```
yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
                 display: false;
                },
```