# Hide volume chart from highstock

Tags: highcharts

I am using highstock candle and volume charts. on button clik of volume i would like to hide the volume chart. However, the volume chart data gets hide and vertical line remain as it is.

|
 |
 | data dispaly gets hide

Thanks,
ShailShin!

Comment: can you give the code what you have worked out.

Comment: the below code for hide the volume chart...function () {

      $(this)
      $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");
      $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
      legendlabel = $(this).text().replace("■ ", "")
      legendlabel = legendlabel.replace("− ", "")

      if (legendlabel == serie.name) {  serie.hide() } and the chart is from below reference...http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle. In general, when you hide series, you should also hide yAxis, see [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277405/highchart-show-hide-an-y-axis-without-hiding-the-series/15292377#15292377) - it's about hiding yAxis (works with or without series).