# Hide Series without hiding y-Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, alignment

There are plenty examples of hiding an [Y-Axis without hiding the series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277405/highchart-show-hide-an-y-axis-without-hiding-the-series) - But i need the opposite of that.

I want to make a series invisible while still displaying the y-axis and i dont know how!

**Why?**

Because i have 2 diagrams which are perfectly aligned by their x-Axis:
[image]

But when i disable both Temperature fields, the axis will be lost, and the diagrams are incorrect in size:
[image]

I also don't like the idea, of disabling all and loosing whole diagram style:
[image]

There is no problem by having an empty diagram, but having a blank box isn't the style i want to reach.

I tried to manipulate the axis in within the [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) event, but selecting the correct axis and set their value visible didn't work out. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: FYI: The second "diagram" is a simple HTML Table - nothing to do with highcharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options:

- play around with [margins](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.margin) - to make them fixed
- set [`min`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min) and [`max`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max) for axis, so labels will remain on a chart: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/70b5j5hv/)

if you don't know min/max values at start you can change them within the legendItemClick as following:

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function() {
                    var temperatur = this.chart.series[0];
                    var taupunkt = this.chart.series[1];
                    var other = this.name=="Lufttemperatur"?taupunkt:temperatur;
                    var element = this;
                    if(this.name == "Lufttemperatur" || this.name == "Taupunkt") {
                        if(this.visible && !other.visible) {
                            //both will be invisible soon
                            this.chart.yAxis[0].update({
                                min:element.yAxis.min,
                                max:element.yAxis.max
                            });
                        } else {
                            //one will be visible
                            this.chart.yAxis[0].update({
                                min:null,
                                max:null
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
 }
```

This will only set min/max if there is no one of your series visible, but deletes it if you have one visible