# Highcharts: Add a button on the chart to hide or show multiple axes

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axes

I have a chart that has 3 y-axes. I have a requirement where the user has the option to show or hide the y-axis on the chart but I need some help getting it to work.

I have added a button on the chart and have tried two different things to get the axis to hide:
(i) Use the show and hide methods on the axis (which produces a console error)
(ii) Set the visible property to trye and false.

Here is the code I have for the button:

```
exporting: {
            buttons: {
                customButton: {
                    text: 'Hide/Show Y-Axis',
                    onclick: function () {

                       /* 
                       /// I get a console error trying to use the hide or show method
                       this.yAxis[0].visible ? this.yAxis[0].hide() : this.yAxis[0].show();

                          */ 

                    if (this.yAxis[0].visible || this.yAxis[1].visible || this.yAxis[2].visible)
                    {
                    this.yAxis[0].visible = false;
                    this.yAxis[1].visible = false;
                    this.yAxis[2].visible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    this.yAxis[0].visible = true;
                    this.yAxis[1].visible = true;
                    this.yAxis[2].visible = true;
                    } 

               this.redraw();

                    }
                } 
            }
        }
```

This seems to do something when it gets to `this.redraw()` but its not hiding the axes. What am I doing wrong here?

Complete code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iwould_/gj203fez/17/)

Thanks

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Use the update method. This is directly related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277405/highchart-show-hide-an-y-axis-without-hiding-the-series)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `update` method on the axes with the new `visible` state

Here is the update `onclick` code:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
      customButton: {
      text: 'Hide/Show Y-Axis',
      onclick: function() {
        this.yAxis.forEach((axis) => {
          axis.update({
            visible: !axis.visible
          })
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8tmvjbhu/2/

Comment: you can remove var newVisState = !visState;

Comment: I made one minor code cleanup edit after the fact. Replaced the `for` loop with the `foreach` loop.