# Remove y-axis gridlines in highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have this chart http://jsfiddle.net/0x48hdff/3/ and i need to remove the x-axis gridlines.

I have tried

```
 gridLineWidth: 0,
 minorGridLineWidth: 0,
```

and setting transparency to zero and i cant seem to hide anything.

How can i hide the -x axis gridlines?.

Update

While the i was able to remove the grid line on the above named chart,i have not yet been able to remove the lines on this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Android Branch'
        },
        credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Seattle HQ',
                'San Francisco',
                'Tokyo'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Employees'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Profit (millions)'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        legend: {
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Employees',
            color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
            data: [150, 73, 20],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Employees Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
            data: [140, 90, 40],
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: -0.2
        }, {
            name: 'Profit',
            color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
            data: [183.6, 178.8, 198.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Profit Optimized',
            color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
            data: [203.6, 198.8, 208.5],
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' M'
            },
            pointPadding: 0.4,
            pointPlacement: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });
});
        </script>
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877927/hide-axis-and-gridlines-highcharts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to remove the grid lines this way

```
{ // Secondary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Companies',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} No',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }
```